# Abelian extensions of the rationals

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Let $E$ and $F$ be finite abelian extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $E\cap F=\mathbb{Q}$. (You could take $E$ and $F$ as cyclotomic fields if that makes my question easier.) Set $K:=EF$ (the field generated by $E$ and $F$). Let $A\supseteq \mathbb{Q}$ be a subfield of $K$. Is it always true that $A$ is generated by $A\cap E$ and $A\cap F$? Thanks for your help.

Edit: Many thanks to Jeremy Rouse for the example. I would like to refine the question as follows.

**Let $E:=\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi/p^a})$ and $F:=\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi/n})$, where $p$ is a prime, $a,n\in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 1}$, and $n$ is relatively prime to $p$. Let $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq A\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi/p^an})$ be a field. Is it always true that $A$ is generated by $A\cap E$ and $A\cap F$?**

Comment: No. Let $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ and $A = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$. Then $A \cap E = A \cap F = \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: No to the refinement. Let $E = \mathbf Q(i) = \mathbf Q(e^{2\pi i/4})$ and $F = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-3}) = \mathbf Q(e^{2\pi i/3})$,  so $K := EF = \mathbf Q(e^{2\pi i/12}) = \mathbf Q(i,\sqrt{-3}) = \mathbf Q(i,\sqrt{3})$. Set $A = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{3})$, so $A \subset K$. Then $A\cap E = \mathbf Q$ and $A \cap F = \mathbf Q$.